# Why does the predict_proba function return 2 columns?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Why does the predict_proba function give 2 columns?

I looked to this website:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict_proba

However, it just says returns: T: array-like of shape (n_samples, n_classes)

Returns the probability of the sample for each class in the model, where classes are ordered as they are in self.classes_.

I still don't understand why the output always returns 2 columns.

```js
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pylab import rcParams
import seaborn as sb 
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
from collections import Counter

from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"

%matplotlib inline
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 5,4
sb.set_style('whitegrid')

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression


import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
file_path = cwd + '\\Default.xlsx' 
default_data = pd.read_excel(file_path)

default_data = pd.read_excel('Default.xlsx')

default_data = default_data.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis=1)
default_data['default_factor'] = default_data.default.factorize()[0]
default_data['student_factor'] = default_data.student.factorize()[0]

X = default_data[['balance']]
y = default_data['default_factor']

lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(X, y)

X_pred = np.linspace(start = 0, stop = 3000, num = 2).reshape(-1,1)
y_pred = lr.predict_proba(X_pred)

X_pred
X_pred.shape
y_pred.shape
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Short answer

In every column it gives you information about the probability, that sample belong to this class (zero column shows the probability for belonging to `class 0`, first column shows the probability for belonging to `class 1` and so on)

##### Detailed answer

Let's say that `y_pred.shape` gives you shape `(2, 2)` means, that you have `2 samples` and `2 classes`.

let's say that your `X_pred` looks like this:

```
 In: print(X_pred)
Out: [[   0.],
      [3000.]]
```

that means that you have two samples:

- `sample one`, with only feature `x = [0]` and
- `sample two`, with only feature `x = [3000]`

let's say that output of your prediction looks like this:

```
In:  print(y_pred)

Out: [[0.28, 0.72]
      [0.65, 0.35]]
```

so it means, that `sample one` most probably belongs to `class = 1` (first row tells you that it could be `class 0` with probability `28%` and `class 1` with probability `72%`)

and `sample two` most probably belongs to `class = 0` (second row tells you that it could be `class 0` with probability `65%` and `class 1` with probability `35%`)

Comment: Can you please tell my why sometimes it only returns a single column? How does one interpret it? Thanks!!